# Symfony 3.1 / Doctrine, Repository or include path wrong

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I got this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct()

I used phpstorm for coding and the line in TestController.php

```
new ProductRepository();
```

is underlined with a message:

> Required parameter $em missing less.
>
> Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared.

But I don't use the `$em` parameter yet.

I use 3 files:

```
AppBundle
    |__Controller
    |            |__ TestController.php
    |__Entity
            |_______ Product.php
            |_______ ProductRepository.php
```

#### TestController.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")

 */
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $pr = new ProductRepository();
    return new Response('OK '.$pr->test());
  }
}
```

#### Product.php:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{ /* ......CODE ...*/}
```

#### ProductRepository.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function test()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get repository through doctrine service, controller returns doctrine service by `getDoctrine` method

```
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $pr = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
    return new Response('OK '.$pr->test());
  }
```

Comment: In this case I want to use the method test who is in ProductRepository from TestController.php,

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't create repositories directly. Use `EntityManager` for this purpose. You can try the following code:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")

 */
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $pr = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository');
    return new Response('OK '.$pr->test());
  }
}
```

Comment: Controllers are initiated by symfony automatically and have methods to get any service including doctrine and entity manager

Comment: @MaxP. I didn't know. Thanks for a tip.